# FFMPEG: How are the parsers providing input bit stream to the decoder

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm having a video decoder integrated into `FFMPEG`. For this decoder i have a parser that reads data from the input bit stream (Elementary stream) and provide the decoder with the data whenever needed. I'm using `fread()` function in my parser to read the input bit stream.

However, when i see the parsers of other available decoder in the `libavcodec/` directory, none of them seems to have a `fread` in them. Tried to figure out this mechanism by debugging the code, but didn't get even a clue regrading the same. So i request if anyone can please provide some explanation regarding how the decoder is getting the required data even though its parsers doesn't seem to have any fread? I mean what is the mechanish being used here to read data from the input file.

Any suggestions/answers regarding the same will be really helpful to me. Kindly do the needful as it can help many people reading this post. Thanks in advance.

--Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `fread()` call comes much earlier in the pipeline -- from the input stage, assuming that the input comes from a file (vs. a network stream or stdin or an optical disc or something else). The demuxer layer (elementary stream in your case) will ask the input layer for data.

Then, *if* you have specified a video bitstream filter via the `-vbsf` command line option, the compressed video data will get passed through that filter before it arrives at the video decoder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1 for the efforts. It would be really great if you can elaborate the first paragraph. I mean i want to know where exactly the file is read and for each frame how the data is being retrieved? Please do reply for this.

Comment: If you really want to see the exact point where file is read from disk, watch the code at libavformat/file.c:file_read(). That's where I expect the action to happen. BTW, it's a read() call rather than an fread().